# TinyMce Editor Pop css override

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce, tinymce-4

I want to override css of all popup in tinymce editor like image upload popup.I tried changing styling using Jquery, is there any way i can override.

Comment: load the tinymce js files from project directory, re-write styles as per requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at creating your own TinyMCE Skin?  The skin creator:

http://skin.tinymce.com

Allows you to change the styles of all aspects of the editor including the dialogs.